# Optimize lookahead in username validation regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to validate usernames with the following rules:

- may only use the characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_`, `.`, and `-`
- the characters `_`, `.`, and `-` cannot be the first or last character
- the characters `_`, `.`, and `-` cannot be next to each other (there must be at least one alphanumeric character between symbols)
- must be between 3 and 15 characters in length, NOT INCLUDING any `_`, `.`, and `-` characters (there must be 3-15 alphanumeric characters)

I'm using the following regex at this time ([click to visualize](http://goo.gl/1q42tr)):

```
/^(?=([A-Za-z0-9][-._]?){3,15}$)[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[-._][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/
```

Any ideas on how to optimize this, especially the lookahead? I tried a lookahead of `(?=[^-._]{3,15})`, but it didn't seem to work. Note that I can only use Javascript-compatible regex.

Comment: Optimize in what way?  Efficiency isn't a legitimate concern in this case, but you can't beat that regex's efficiency anyway.  Are you just trying to make the regex itself more compact?  That's not worth the effort.  Your regex is exactly what I would have written.

Comment: @AlanMoore Thanks. It seems like the lookahead could be simpler. Something more like `(?=[^-._]{3,15})`, but unfortunately that doesn't work.

Comment: Your regex looks good, and that's what I would suggest you to use.

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks for checking it out for me. I'll use it and not worry about further optimization or making it more compact.

Answer (score 2):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I’ll use regular expressions!” Now they have two problems.　—Jamie Zawinsky

Regular expressions may be helpful in validating the username, but you shouldn’t try to pack it all into one regular expression—that way lies madness. Instead, break it up:

```
function isValidUsername(username) {
    // may only use the characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _, ., and -
    // the characters _, ., and - cannot be the first or last character
    if(!/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]$/.test(username)) {
        return false;
    }
    // the characters _, ., and - cannot be next to each other
    // (there must be at least one alphanumeric character between symbols)
    if(/[_.-]{2}/.test(username)) {
        return false;
    }
    // must be between 3 and 15 characters in length,
    // NOT INCLUDING any _, ., and - characters
    // (there must be 3-15 alphanumeric characters)
    var filteredUsername = username.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
    if(filteredUsername.length < 3 || filteredUsername.length > 15) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I think the result is much more maintainable than packing it all into one regular expression, and you probably won’t have any performance problems with it, either.

Comment: That's the answer! +1 PS: one in the final solution might even split the first check to 2: one that checks all characters fall in the allowed range and the other that checks if it starts with alphanumerics, so that it was possible to tell a user exactly what their fault is.

Comment: I understand your perspective, but that is exactly what I'd prefer to avoid until I absolutely have too. I'm using jsonschema for validation and it is much cleaner if I can use regex. Of course, regex can't solve every problem, but for this application, I haven't run into it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Primarily, the pattern below should be work

```
[a-zA-Z0-9](?:(?![_\.\-]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

From you conditions:

> CONDITION: the characters _, ., and - cannot be the first or last character

```
REGEX: [a-zA-Z0-9]...[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

and

> CONDITION: may only use the characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _, ., and -

```
REGEX: [a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+
```

and

> CONDITION: the characters _, ., and - cannot be next to each other

```
REGEX:(?![_\.\-]{2})
```

*here just use negative lookahead to check it

**BUT...**

The last condition

> CONDITION: must be between 3 and 15 characters in length, NOT INCLUDING any _, .,
>   and characters (there must be 3-15 alphanumeric characters)

to verify pattern by counting only alphanumeric characters, I have no idea.

**My conclusion is**

I don't think the last condition can be fit by a pure regular expression, once you use `[...]+` to generate matchers of random patterns then how you can use lookahead to verify those patterns, if you don't know exactly pattern ahead.

Comment: I think your lookahead was supposed to be `(?!.*[_.-]{2})`, to scan the *whole string* looking for two consecutive specials.  And, as you said, you're not enforcing the three-to-fifteen alphanumerics rule at all.  I don't know if you noticed, but the OP's regex *does* meet all of the requirements.  He's just asking if it can be improved.  (It can't.)

Comment: @AlanMoore The problem is there is no solution by using pure regex, `[...]+` generates a random pattern, then how we can use lookahead to catch the random generated pattern.

Comment: @terces907 Thank you for your thoughts. The regex I provided does meet my requirements, including the 3-15 alphanum characters. I am wondering if someone had any ideas on making it better.

Comment: @terces907: I like this way of answering a question. Note that it is not a problem for a regex to count specific characters delimited with other symbols, but it just looks a bit "crammed".

Comment: `(?![_\.\-]{2})` doesn't work to prevent consecutive instances of `_`, `.` or `-`. You need to check with every repetition: `(?:(?![_.-]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+`

Answer (score 0):

You may use a pure 1-regex solution with an optimized last part:

```
^(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]){3,15}[^a-zA-Z0-9]*$)(?![._-])(?!.*[._-][._-])[\w.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dI1oP2/1) (note that `\n` is added to character classes for demo purposes in multiline mode).

This regex can be made more maintainable and readable if a pseudo-verbose style of writing the regex is applied:

```js
var re = RegExp(
  "^" +                   // Beginning of a string              
  "(?=(?:[^a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9]){3,15}[^a-z0-9]*$)" + // Must contain 3-15 alphanums
  "(?![._-])" +           // Cannot start with ., _ or -
  "(?!.*[._-][._-])" +    // Cannot contain consecutive .-, -_, .., --, etc.
  "[\\w.-]+[a-z0-9]" + // Consists of alphanums only and ends with a letter or digit
  "$",                    // End of a string
      "i");               // Make the pattern case-insensitive
                 
var str = 'azzz-zzzzzzz_AZ0.9';
document.write(str + ": " + re.test(str)+"<br/>");
str = '.azzzzzzz-A_Z09';
document.write(str + ": " + re.test(str));
```

Also, please note that the `(?=(?:[^a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9]){3,15}[^a-z0-9]*$)` lookahead follows the [*regex principle of contrast*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast):

> When you can, use consecutive tokens that are mutually exclusive in order to create contrast. This reduces backtracking and the need for boundaries in the broad sense of the term, in which I include lookarounds.

If you prefer to keep your own regex, I'd still advise to comment it and use a case-insensitive `i` modifier to shorten it a tiny bit:

```js
var re = RegExp(
  "^" +                           // Beginning of a string              
  "(?=([a-z0-9][-._]?){3,15}$)" + // Must contain 3-15 alphanums (NOTE: only works if [-._] cannot follow one another)
  "[a-z0-9]+" +                   // Cannot start with ., _ or -, starts only with letter or digit
  "(?:[-._][a-z0-9]+)*" +         // Cannot contain consecutive [._-], does not start/end with [-._]
  "$",                            // End of a string
      "i");                       // Make pattern case insensitive
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your suggestion. However, your regex seems more complex than the one I have already provided. Is there an advantage to it that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure how this is any better than the regex in the question.

Comment: Actually, there are at least three: 1) the last part is contracted from `(?:[-._][A-Za-z0-9]+)*` to `[A-Za-z0-9]`, 2) comments in a pseudo verbose mode, 3) opposite character classes are used in the first lookahead that is a generic way of checking length of specific symbols in a string. You decide whether it is of any use to you. If not, I will delete the answer. Actually, it is not a good task definition *to make it better*. I think that to make it better is just using comments for each subpattern.

Comment: @nhahtdh: I think that in such questions, it is up to OP to decide if it is helpful or not.

Comment: @Tauren: At any rate, you can shorten your regex with `i` modifier, and use comments for readabilty. I just provided some sample comments, still hope it is helpful.